# Continues loop, with no loop

Tags: java

this is my code, the problem is that when it is run there is a problem with the JOptionPane.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class MoveTyper extends JFrame
{
int Location[] = {40, 40};
public static void main (String args[])
{
    new MoveTyper();
}

public MoveTyper() 
{
    super("typetomove");
    setSize(800, 450);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    System.out.println("poop");
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);


        g.fillRect(Location[0], Location[1], 20, 20);

        String Axis = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Move by X or by Y? If you would like to quit, type cancel");

            int Movement = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How Many would you like to move up from"));
            if(Axis.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
            {
                Location[0] = Location[0] + Movement;
            }
            else if(Axis.equalsIgnoreCase("cancel"))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                Location[1] = Location[1] + Movement;


    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have quit. GOOD JOB. YOU SMELL");


}
```

}
When it is run, the JOptionPane continues to pop-up (one on top of the other), as if in a loop, may you guys help me figure out the problem? I cannot seem to find the problem.

Comment: The `paint()` method runs every time the component needs to be redrawn, for example when it is moved or re-sized. When you first pop up a JOptionPane, it pops on top of your component, meaning that when you select out of it, the component needs to be re-drawn. So the `paint()` method runs again, showing yet another JOptionPane, and going on forever.

Comment: @Kon you should post it as answer.

Comment: Hmm... ok, so I don't completely understand, but what would I need to do to fix this?

Comment: @Kon your comments should be an answer

Answer (score 0):

Code from `showInputDialog()` to `showMessageDialog()` should not be in `paint()`method. Move it out to a new method:

```
public void showDialog() {
    String Axis = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Move by X or by Y? If you would like to quit, type cancel");

    int Movement = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How Many would you like to move up from"));
    if(Axis.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
    {
        Location[0] = Location[0] + Movement;
    }
    else if(Axis.equalsIgnoreCase("cancel"))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        Location[1] = Location[1] + Movement;


    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have quit. GOOD JOB. YOU SMELL");
}
```

and in your case, call this method from the Constructor

```
public MoveTyper() 
{
    super("typetomove");
    setSize(800, 450);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    showDialog();
}
```

So the `paint()`method looks like this

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    System.out.println("poop");
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(Location[0], Location[1], 20, 20);
}
```